# Is there any way to check if a hex number is in the collection of hex numbers in one step?

Tags: validation, encryption, hex

I wanna check if `AD18EB94E` is in the collection of hex numbers below in a single step.

`22012FA58`
`AD18EB94E`
`11012FA58`

Is there any method to validate it? may be encoding all the three hex numbers and produce a one single hex number and compare it with the original? or may be I wanna convert it into binary and validate? what are the methods that I can try?

**PS: single step is:** `NOT iterating` through list of provided 3 hex numbers one by one, to check if the original number is in the list of numbers.

I have trillions of these hex numbers and if I go through the number by number in the list it would take years to find a match. So I'm looking for some method to check it in single step without going one by one, so I can find a match without wasting months to find a single match in the list. may be hashing all the list numbers and make a one hash number etc and compare it with the original in some way. IDK.

Comment: *what are the methods that I can try?* You'd have to specify a programming language first. Most languages provide a set type or at least a dictionary/map/hashtable type that permits checking for set membership in one step, sometimes even with a special operator for convenience and clarity.

Comment: it's `VSCode- visual basic`, but it doesn't matter I guess, as I'm not looking for language specific functions etc. I wanna know ways/methods that people have managed to validate if that the first number is in the collection.

Comment: Can you define „in one single step“? It’s quite unspecific. It could be single line of code, a single instruction, but then, how if it’s a function? For example, you could do this with a regex which is only a single instruction for you, but a lot of instructions internally.

Comment: single step is: `NOT iterating` through list of provided 3 hex numbers one by one to check if the original number is in the list of numbers. 
probable single step: hashing all three hex numbers and comparing with the original one to see if there's a match, IDK though, this is just a pseudo single step.